# Helm configmap template not working when using files

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configMap.name | quote }}
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.configMap.name | quote }}
data:
  application.yaml: |-
{{ .Files.Get "application.yaml" | indent 4}}
  otherFile.csv: |-
{{ .Files.Get "otherFile.csv" | indent 4}}
```

But I want to make the configmap more generic, so I was thinking on something like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configMap.name | quote }}
  labels:
    name: {{ .Values.configMap.name | quote }}
data:
  {{- range $data := .Values.configMap.data }}
  {{ $data }}: |-
    {{ .Files.Get $data | indent 4}}
  {{- end}}
```

And in the values.yaml to have something like this:

```
configMap:
  name: app-configmap
  data:
    - application.yaml
    - otherFile.csv
```

If I don't make it generic it works, but if I try to make it generic I get errors:

```
executing "app/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Files.AsConfig>: wrong number of args for AsConfig: want 0 got 1
helm.go:84: [debug] template: app/templates/configmap.yaml:10:9: executing "app/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Files.AsConfig>: wrong number of args for AsConfig: want 0 got 1
```

Any hint?

Comment: Your error message doesn't seem to match your code; can you check that you've included the right template and error in your question?

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze , it seems like your error message is not matching your template code. Also, what you're trying to achieve sounds a lot to me as if you need to work with helm's [glob patterns](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#glob-patterns)